# Forcing pdftex to be in pdf mode

Tags: pdftex

I have a rather complex macro to produce pdf figures in landscape mode.

1. When I include the macro in the body of the main file, the code runs fine.
2. When I put the macro in a separate style file, latex cannot determine the size of the graphic.
3. when I put the macro in a separate style file *and* precede the macro with an `\includegraphics` command, the code runs fine.

Looking at the log, the difference is that in case 1 and 3) I have

```
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 91.
```

and then

```
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in pdf mode detected
```

In case 2, I have

```
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91
```

and then

```
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in pdf mode not detected
```

So the question is, how can I induce case 2 the behavior I get in case 1 and 3.

I'm sure this question can be answered without the details of my code, but I'm including it just in case. Here's the main latex code for case 3.    Case 2 can be created by commenting out the `\includegraphics` line third from the bottom. Case 1 can be created by replacing the line `\usepackage{landscapePdfPic}` with the actual code, below

```
\documentclass{amsart}%
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage{environ}            
\usepackage{landscapePdfPic}
\def\figureDir{.}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{pic.pdf}
\landscapePdfPic{\figureDir}{pic}
\end{document}
```

Here's the content of `landscapePdfPic.sty`:

```
\providecommand{\LAYOUT}[5]{%
  \setlength{\hoffset}{0pt}
  \setlength{\voffset}{0pt}
  \setlength{\topmargin}{#1 - 1in - \voffset - \headheight - \headsep}
  \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{#2 - 1in - \hoffset}
  \setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}
  \setlength{\textheight}{#3}
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#4}
  \setlength{\marginparwidth}{#5}
}
\providecommand{\ARTPAGE}{\LAYOUT{1.5 in}{1.75 in}{8 in}{5 in}{1.5 in}}
\providecommand{\FULLPAGE}{\LAYOUT{1 in}{1 in}{9 in}{6.5 in}{0.75 in}}

\def\topVerticalOffset{-120pt}%Negative value moves the top of the pic up the page
\def\topHorizontalOffset{-160pt}%Negative value moves the top of the left
\def\widthMultiplier{2.4}%How much to blow up the picture horizontally, relative to \textwidth
\def\heightMultiplier{1.6}%How much to blow up the picture vertically, relative to \textheight

\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\landscapePdfPic}{%
O{\topVerticalOffset}
O{\topHorizontalOffset}
O{\widthMultiplier}
O{\heightMultiplier}
m m o o }{
    \newpage
    \IfNoValueTF{#7}
        {\def\hideCaptionOffset{3in}}
        {
            \@ifmtarg{#7}
            {\def\hideCaptionOffset{3in}}
            {\def\hideCaptionOffset{-0.58in}}}
    \ARTPAGE
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    $\empty$\\[#1]
    $\empty$\hspace*{#2}
    \includegraphics[width=#3\textwidth,height=#4\textheight] {#5/#6.pdf}
    \vspace*{\hideCaptionOffset}
    \caption{#7}
    \vspace*{-\hideCaptionOffset}

    \IfNoValueTF{#8}
        {\label{fig:#6}}
        {\@ifmtarg{#8}
            {\label{fig:#6}}
            {\label{fig:#8}}}
    \vspace*{-30pt}
    \thepage
    \end{figure}
    \end{landscape}
    \FULLPAGE
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: `\pdfoutput=1`?

Comment: haven't you used latex in some cases and pdflatex in the others (hard to guess why the correct option isn't defaulted otherwise)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, the only difference is, that `latex` was used for case 2 and `pdflatex` for the other cases. Therefore, case 2 has loaded the `graphics` driver `dvips.def` as default driver, which is not able to include PDF files.

The output format should not be changed by a package. It confuses the user, if he runs `pdflatex` and gets `DVI` and vise versa.

But you can add a warning, if the file is compiled with the wrong mode.
Addition for the package:

```
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\else
  \PackageWarning{landscapePdfPic}{Wrong mode, PDF expected}%
  % or \PackageError{landscapePdfPic}{Wrong mode, PDF expected}\@ehc
  %
  % As error recovery, dummy definitions for the macros, provided by
  % the package could be given.
  %
  % \expandafter\endinput % possibility to end a package early at this place
\fi
```

Comment: Arrgh, sorry what a dummy.    My latex macro checks content to decide whether to run latex (if I have .eps files) or pdflatex (if I have .pdf files).    So stupid not to realize that!       Thanks!